# SQL Aggregate on Two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Table A has millions of records from 2014, Using Oracle

```
ID   Sales_Amount  Sales_Date
1      10           20/11/2014
1      10           22/11/2014
1      10           22/12/2014
1      10           22/01/2015     
1      10           22/02/2015         
1      10           22/03/2015     
1      10           22/04/2015     
1      10           22/05/2015 
1      10           22/06/2015     
1      10           22/07/2015
1      10           22/08/2015
1      10           22/09/2015    
1      10           22/10/2015     
1      10           22/11/2015
```

Table B

```
ID   ID_Date
1    22/11/2014
2    01/12/2014
```

I want sum of totals for 6 months as well as 1 year for ID 1 taking starting
date from Table B as **22/11/2014**

```
Output Sales_Amount_6Months Sales_Amount_6Months
1               70                 130
```

Shall I use `add_months` in this case?

Comment: Provide the query which you have tried out

Comment: How do you decide to take the date 22/11/2014 from table B, and not the other date? Do you take the "oldest" date from table B? Also: What is "6 months" - from 22/11/2014 to 21/5/2015?

Comment: The aggregation of totals takes the date from Table B as minimum date which is 22/11/2014 for ID1, and from that date we need to calculate 6 months totals and 12 months totals from Table B, please do add_months(22-11-2014,6) & add_months(22-11-2014,12) for 12 months

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ADD_MONTHS()` and conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT b.id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.sales_date between b.id_date AND ADD_MONTHS(b.id_date,6) THEN a.sales_amount ELSE 0 END) as sales_6_month,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.sales_date between b.id_date AND ADD_MONTHS(b.id_date,12) THEN a.sales_amount ELSE 0 END) as sales_12_month
FROM TableB b
JOIN TableA a
 ON(b.id = a.id)
GROUP BY b.id
```